# How do I set Postfix to now send MAILER-DAEMON messages

Tags: postfix

One of my domains is being spoofed as a 'from' address and all of the rejects are coming back to my server. I am getting 400-500 per minute. I am trying to get the registrar to help set up an SPF record so that this will not happen, but can I set some parameter in sender_access to block sending these to me?

I tried adding:

```
MAILER-DAEMON@mydomain.com  REJECT  (which is the 'from' address on these bounces)
```

to my `sender_access` file. But to no avail. Perhaps this doesn't work because this isn't really an incoming message, but one generated by postfix?

I also added:

```
check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access,
```

to the `smtpd_sender_restrictions` section of `main.cf`.

Is there an easier way to stop sending me these hundreds of emails?

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: First, blacklist every mail server that sent you these backscatter messages. They never should have been generated in the first place. After that, well, this is a hard problem. You may find some hints at http://www.postfix.org/BACKSCATTER_README.html

Comment: But there are thousands. Someone has decided to spam with me as the 'sender'. I wouldn't know how to begin.

Comment: Well, you can gain a lot of experience, then. This is one of the biggest reasons why so many people no longer run their own mail servers.

Comment: Yea, This is just fora couple of hobby accounts I have. :) I should probably stick them on google for business or something. Btu it's fun! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The email you are receiving the emails at, should be in your `recipient_access` file, not sender access.  An option instead of `REJECT` is to `DISCARD` the emails instead.  Your server will 'accept' the message and delete the email.  The external email server will think it was delivered correctly, but you won't have a full mailbox.

Fixing your SPF records will help a lot so the external mail servers hopefully won't even accept the message to begin with assuming it's spam.